# Difference between "premiss" and "premise"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In speaking of propositions, not buildings, are *premise* and *premiss* variant spellings of the same word, or are they different terms with different usages? The *American Heritage Dictionary* (3/e) gives *premise* as the main entry, with *premiss* as a variant spelling, which I've assumed was British. But [one internet source](http://logic-rhetoric.livejournal.com/1079.html?nojs=1) asserts that *premiss* is preferable because of its etymology; [another](http://www.talktalk.co.uk/reference/dictionaries/english/data/d0082622.html) suggests that *premiss* is always the correct term in logic.

Comment: Related: [What's the correct plural form of “premise”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2546)

Comment: Isn't a "premiss" someone too young to be a [Little Miss](https://www.mrmen.com/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OED has *premiss* only as a variant spelling of *premise*, and has a note "In Logic still freq. in form *premiss*, but in general use now usu. in form *premise*. (I can't find a date on the entry, but it includes a citation from 2000) 
 "

Answer (score 1):

Premiss when taken as a logical postulate upon which a philosophical argument is founded.

Premise when a mere, as yet unfounded, presumption.

So one is a subset of the other. They may be interchangeable but not always.

Comment: Says who? How do we know if your answer is correct or if you're just some dude on the internet making things up? The other answer, with a score of 5 and accepted by the OP, says you're wrong and cites the OED to prove it. Who can you cite?

Comment: Premises are, strictly speaking, purported reasons given to support a conclusion. Whether the premises give airtight support for the conclusion (deductive) or a weaker type of support (inductive), that is the job of logical analysis. Therefore logical postulates are premises in the sense that they are cited as a reason to support a conclusion, but we usually call such premises 'axioms' to distinguish them from non-axiomatic premises. Axioms are statements upon which we base theories and which cannot be derived from other statements (or we choose not to derive them, for economy sake).